# Can't add the same item on multiple xfce panels

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce

I'd like to know if there is a way to force adding an item on multiple panels on xfce.

I'm talking about dockbarx and notifications that can be used only on one panel.

I'm on a multiple monitor environment, so i'd really like to be able to use them on all my monitors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeRtm.png

[Greyed out option on xfce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lnfx.png)

Comment: I think it is not possible for good reason. Another panel plugin called "Notification Area" is also limited to only one instance in Xfce panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2 panels. It is possible to add an app to both of the panels. Open menu and right click on the app and click "add to panel". Then select your desired panel.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, the option to add again the dockbarx item is greyed out, this means i can't add more than one time that item.

Comment: take a look at this - http://i.imgur.com/YZ5Ujbc.png

Comment: This creates a launcher, i'm not seeking for the launcher, i'm seeking for the plugin.